# Is it legal to use the #line directive in a macro argument?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc

I noticed that this program compiles with gcc:

```
#define X(A) A

int x = X(
#line 3 "test1.c"
        0
        );
```

However, Visual Studio fails to compile it:

```
main.cpp
main.cpp(6): error C2121: '#': invalid character: possibly the result of a macro expansion
main.cpp(6): error C2065: 'line': undeclared identifier
main.cpp(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
main.cpp(6): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
```

I wonder: is the program even legal, or is it silently relying on undefined (or implementation defined) behaviour which happens to make gcc accept the code?

Comment: #line is in the standard, but it may be that Visual studio tries to feed "#line 3 \"test1.c\"\n0\n" into the macro, while GCC evaluates the #line before feeding it into X

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's invalid. The behaviour is undefined, so no diagnostic is required, and implementations are allowed to accept the code.

From the C standard, 6.10.3 Macro replacement:

> 11 [...] If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined.

The C++ standard contains these exact same words in 16.3 Macro replacement.

Comment: To be strict no diagnostic is required because this paragraph is within _Semantics_ section. For instance the explicit undefined behaviour in _Constraints_ section requires diagnostic, as by 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics: `if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
specified as undefined or implementation-defined`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski There is no constraint anywhere that gives a rule, and says the behaviour is undefined if the rule is violated. I think 5.1.1.3 refers to programs that have separate independent errors, some constraint violations, and others undefined behaviour.

Comment: That really makes sense, especially because of "implementation-defined" behaviour, that is also never encountered there, in constaint.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile the example with all warnings, gcc gives you:

> warning: embedding a directive within macro arguments is not portable

and clang gives you:

> warning: embedding a directive within macro arguments has undefined behavior

which definitely strongly suggests to me that the behavior is, indeed, undefined.